# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/run/wpa_supplicant'

Tags: python, wifi, wpa

Could anyone please help with fixing the following import error when running wifiutil_linux.py? Thanks a lot.

```
    280         ifaces = []
--> 281         for f in sorted(os.listdir(CTRL_IFACE_DIR)):
    282             sock_file = '/'.join([CTRL_IFACE_DIR, f])
    283             mode = os.stat(sock_file).st_mode

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/run/wpa_supplicant'
```

Comment: Without more factual information it. I'm guessing its failing to create the folder if it doesn't exist. I'm basing my findings on reviewing the script on github <https://github.com/project-owner/Peppy/blob/master/util/wifiutil.py> Copyright 2019-2020 Peppy Player peppy.player@gmail.com

Comment: @NeoTheNerd  More factual information has now been added to the question. Could you please help with fixing the following import error when running wifiutil_linux.py? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does the directory exist? directory_exists = ("/var/run/wpa_supplicant")